# connecting node js to postgresql on heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed my app on heroku and was able to make a connection to the database from pg:psql in my terminal by copying and pasting the code provided by heroku. Now i want to directly connect my node app to postgres on heroku but no success. I followed the instruction on heroku on how to connect nodejs to postgres here.. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js but i can't seem to get it to work. I simply installed pg module and pasted the block of code provided by heroku inside my get request in my server.js file.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/food', function(req, res) {
    pg.defaults.ssl = true;
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...');
        client.query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;').on('row', function(row) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
        });
    });
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log('listening to port 3000!');
});
```

the error i get from heroku logs is..

```
/appserver.js:53
if (err) throw err;

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.0.1:5432
```

after searching for that error message, i get some people suggesting on fixing or changing the DATABASE_URL. How and where do i change it? I'm lost. I would really appreciated if i can get some help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The pg connection is using the database url in your environment:

```
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {}
```

Because the DATABASE_URL env variable is not set, it defaults to localhost `127.0.0.0.1:5432`. You can set DATABASE_URL in your [bashrc or bash_profile](https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-2cb45a55195f#.vceizs3ip). You can name it more specifically PROJECTNAME_DATABASE_URL if you have multiple apps. On Heroku, you can set it like this:

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@host:port/database
```